# Umbrella header file not updating after changing any swift code

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, swift

I have a Mix project of Swift and Objective C. Initially I created a the project choosing Swift as language. 
I have Objective C Bridging headers working absolutely fine - as I add any new obj c code that I manually update in Header file.
I imported "ProjectName-Swift.h" file in obj c and It worked fine. Now when I change any code in my swift files or add new swift files I can see "ProjectName-Swift.h" file is not updated with new changes. I tried to manually change the file and it worked. 
I cleaned the project and rebuilt but no luck. I deleted the generated "ProjectName-Swift.h" file and tried building but still new changes are not shown.

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8MyProject13Type2")
@interface Type2 : NSObject
+ (Type2 *)sharedInstance;
- (float)method1:(Type2 *)entity amount:(float)amount;
- (float)method2:(Type1 *)category amount:(float)amount;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I know this was a long time ago, but I just struggled with the same problem when adding a protocol to my Swift code, and it wasn't being added to the -Swift.h header file.

The problem was my protocol wasn't marked as *Public*. I changed my protocol from this:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol { //etc.... }
```

to this:

```
@objc public protocol MyProtocol { //etc.... }
```

Comment: This would only solve the problem if you were vending a framework or library; the default access scope is `internal` so `public` won't have an effect within the project.